# node-parse-api multiple include keys

Tags: node.js, api, parsing, parse-platform, include

Today I started to work with this API for Parse and is very easy to understand and implement I have almost done all my work, but I have a problem and I couldn't find documentation about it,

Is about having multiple pointers in a find query

This is what i did, but only get one of includes

```
var query = {
            where: {type: 'OK'}, 
            include: 'dataLink1', 
            include: 'dataLink2', 
            limit: 1000
        }
        app.find('_User', query, function (err, response) {
            if (response === undefined) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(error, 401);
            }
            return res.send(response);
        });
```

If somebody need the link of the API, this is

https://github.com/Leveton/node-parse-api

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem

```
var query = {
        where: {type: 'OK'}, 
        include: 'dataLink1, dataLink2', 
        limit: 1000
    }
    app.find('_User', query, function (err, response) {
        if (response === undefined) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(error, 401);
        }
        return res.send(response);
    });
```